# K-Means: assign clusters to new data points

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I've implemented a k-means clustering algorithm in python, and now I want to label a new data with the clusters I got with my algorithm. My approach is to iterate through every data point and every centroid to find the minimum distance and the centroid associated with it. But I wonder if there are simpler or shorter ways to do it.

```
def assign_cluster(clusterDict, data):

    clusterList = []
    label = []
    cen = list(clusterDict.values())

    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(cen)):
            # if cen[j] has the minimum distance with data[i]
            # then clusterList[i] = cen[j]
```

Where `clusterDict` is a dictionary with keys as labels, [0,1,2,....] and values as coordinates of centroids.

Can someone help me implementing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for numba, because it lets you express this as a simple double loop without a big performance penalty, which in turn allows you to avoid the excessive extra memory of using `np.tile` to replicate the data across a third dimension just to do it in a vectorized manner.

Borrowing the standard vectorized numpy implementation from the other answer, I have these two implementations:

```
import numba
import numpy as np


def kmeans_assignment(centroids, points):
    num_centroids, dim = centroids.shape
    num_points, _ = points.shape

    # Tile and reshape both arrays into `[num_points, num_centroids, dim]`.                                                                      
    centroids = np.tile(centroids, [num_points, 1]).reshape([num_points, num_centroids, dim])
    points = np.tile(points, [1, num_centroids]).reshape([num_points, num_centroids, dim])

    # Compute all distances (for all points and all centroids) at once and                                                                       
    # select the min centroid for each point.                                                                                                    
    distances = np.sum(np.square(centroids - points), axis=2)
    return np.argmin(distances, axis=1)


@numba.jit
def kmeans_assignment2(centroids, points):
    P, C = points.shape[0], centroids.shape[0]
    distances = np.zeros((P, C), dtype=np.float32)
    for p in range(P):
        for c in range(C):
            distances[p, c] = np.sum(np.square(centroids[c] - points[p]))
    return np.argmin(distances, axis=1)
```

Then for some sample data, I did a few timing experiments:

```
In [12]: points = np.random.rand(10000, 50)

In [13]: centroids = np.random.rand(30, 50)

In [14]: %timeit kmeans_assignment(centroids, points)
196 ms ± 6.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [15]: %timeit kmeans_assignment2(centroids, points)
127 ms ± 12.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I won't go as far to say that the numba version is certainly faster than the `np.tile` version, but clearly it's very close while not incurring the extra memory cost of `np.tile`.

In fact, I noticed for my laptop that when I make the shapes larger and use (10000, 1000) for the shape of `points` and (200, 1000) for the shape of `centroids`, then `np.tile` generated a `MemoryError`, meanwhile the `numba` function runs in under 5 seconds with no memory error.

Separately, I actually noticed a slowdown when using `numba.jit` on the first version (with`np.tile`), which is likely due to the extra array creation inside the jitted function combined with the fact that there's not much numba can optimize when you're already calling all vectorized functions.

And I also did not notice any significant improvement in the second version when trying to shorten the code by using broadcasting. E.g. shortening the double loop to be

```
for p in range(P):
    distances[p, :] = np.sum(np.square(centroids - points[p, :]), axis=1)
```

did not really help anything (and would use more memory when repeatedly broadcasting `points[p, :]` across all of `centroids`).

This is one of the really nice benefits of numba. You really can write the algorithms in a very straightforward, loop-based way that comports with standard descriptions of algorithms and allows finer point of control over how the syntax unpacks into memory consumption or broadcasting... all without giving up runtime performance.

Comment: Your timings for the Numba function seems weird. I get 170ms for the kmeans_assignment, 51,2ms for the function you provided and 4,36ms for a parallelized version using prange on the outer loop. (Quadcore i7) Which Numba Version are you using? Have you compiled the function before the benchmark run?

Comment: @max9111 The numba version is 0.35.0, and yes, I always make sure to warm the compiled version by calling it with different arguments of the same types (to generate the compiled version), before the timeit statement. I consistently see the speed I listed for my machine, but your results suggest it can be even faster with additional optimization. Really the only point is that `np.tile` should be avoided because of its significant extra memory overhead.

Comment: I used Numba 0.38 RC1. There may be very significant changes regarding SIMD-vectorization and also sorting-speed. Intrinistics like sqrt, pow, sin can be now vectorized, which adds significant speedups. http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way to perform assignment phase is by doing *vectorized* computation. This approach assumes that you start with two 2D arrays: points and centroids, with the same number of columns (dimensionality of space), but possibly different number of rows. By using tiling ([`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)) we can then compute the distance matrix in a batch, then select the closest clusters per each point.

Here's the code:

```py
def kmeans_assignment(centroids, points):
  num_centroids, dim = centroids.shape
  num_points, _ = points.shape

  # Tile and reshape both arrays into `[num_points, num_centroids, dim]`.
  centroids = np.tile(centroids, [num_points, 1]).reshape([num_points, num_centroids, dim])
  points = np.tile(points, [1, num_centroids]).reshape([num_points, num_centroids, dim])

  # Compute all distances (for all points and all centroids) at once and 
  # select the min centroid for each point.
  distances = np.sum(np.square(centroids - points), axis=2)
  return np.argmin(distances, axis=1)
```

See [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/maxim5/606b54fee4f5c6ebfda80225d103181c) for a complete runnable example.